# To exclude Class from Body on Click eevent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Toggle a Class on body click. But if specific DIV having class "mainDIV" is reflecting on the same body then I want to
exclude body click event for that DIV. So that when user click on "mainDIV" body click event must not be occur.

I am using this CODE in jQuery but its not working:

```
$("body :not(.mainDIV)").bind("click", function() {
  $('.offerClass').show();
});
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Is the `.mainDIV` class set on your body Element? that's not really clear from your question.

Comment: @LuudJacobs .maindiv class is not applied on body. In middle of the body there is a div on which it is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) method is deprecated in jQuery `3.0` so it's better to go with [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead.

Bind click event on `body` and prevent event bubbling up when clicked inside `.mainDIV` using [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method.

```
$("body").on("click", function() {
  $('.offerClass').show();
}).on('click','.mainDIV',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that `bind()` was deprecated some time ago. You should now use `on()` instead.

To solve your issue you could let the event bubble up to the `document` and then check the class on the element referenced in the `target` of the event, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('mainDIV'))
    $('.offerClass').show();
});
```

Comment: If there is nested element within `.mainDIV` ?? there is a chance to target them(`e.target`)..... I think an additional condition `!$(e.target).closest('.mainDIV').length`  would be fine